# How to redirect users to their own profile page?

Tags: php, url, redirect

All users have their own profile page:

```
www.mysite.com/profile.php?id=13
```

What I am trying to do now is redirect them to their own profile page in case they only type:

```
www.mysite.com/profile.php
```

I've tried this but I keep on getting a redirect loop:

```
 if ((preg_match("{(?:profile)\.php$}", $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])) && 
 (!empty($_SESSION["id"])) )
     {
         redirect ("profile.php?id=$id");        
     }
```

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] will always return profile.php in case it is appended with id or not ie. why your regex always matches fine and you are moving in a redirect loop forever

Why dont you make the regex like this:-

```
if ((preg_match("/^\/profile\.php$/", $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])) && 
 (!empty($_SESSION["id"])) )
     {
         redirect ("profile.php?id=$id");        
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It doesnt seem to work though: doesn't redirect at all...

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` contains the filename of the currently executing script, so your condition will always match.

I would use something like:

```
if ( empty($_GET['id') && !empty($_SESSION['id']) )
```